# Find and replace in query string using regex

Tags: python, regex

So I am trying to check for credentials in the query string and replace the password with "ak_redacted", if one is found.

sample string:

```
a=123&b=456&userName=abc&password=xyz&key=1&value=2
```

This should become :

```
a=123&b=456&userName=abc&password=ak_redacted&key=1&value=2
```

Trying to use the below snippet but it does not seem to work

```
qs = request['querystring']
print(qs)
updatedqs = ''
if "password" in params:
  if "userName" in params:
    updatedqs = re.sub(r"/(?=((.*)password)=([^&]+)(.*)|).+/g", r"\1=ak_redacted\4", qs)
    print(updatedqs)
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use a method to parser the url, but `(?<=\bpassword=)[^&]+` and replace with `ak_redacted` or  `([?&]password=)[^&]+` and replace with `\1ak_redacted` https://regex101.com/r/Q7ro4G/1

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are looking for two literal slashes with a literal `g` after the second. (Did you come from PHP by any chance? Bletch.) But the regex itself after you take those out also looks way too complex and probably simply wrong. How are you hoping this should work?

Comment: Why don't you parse the query string into a dictionary. Then you can do `d['password'] = 'ak_redacted'`, and finally convert the dictionary back into a query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlencode

query_string = "a=123&b=456&userName=abc&password=xyz&key=1&value=2"
parsed_query = dict(parse_qsl(query_string))

if parsed_query.get("password"):
    parsed_query["password"] = "ak_redacted"

redacted_query_string = urlencode(parsed_query)

print(redacted_query_string)
```

**Output:**

```
a=123&b=456&userName=abc&password=ak_redacted&key=1&value=2
```